# How to display all the usernames? Tried tolist() but that does not work

Tags: c#, database, exception, mdf

`query.First().Username;`

`query.tolist()`

don't give option about username.

Comment: even that doesn't work man...jammed since yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

```
query.Select(x => x.Username).ToList();
```

This will give you a list of all the usernames

Comment: 'schoolmanagement.Student' does not contain a definition for 'Username' and no extension method 'Username' accepting a first argument of type 'schoolmanagement.Student' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `query.First().Username;` if this works then you are doing something else incorrect